# How do I flag a tag for moderator attention?

Tags: discussion, tags, flags, tag-wiki

[This tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/password-hashing/info) recently ended up in my review queue, which I promptly rejected due to it being a verbatim copy from http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php without attribution.  Unfortunately other editors weren't as deligent and it was accepted.  Sorry if this has been asked before but how would one flag a tag for moderator attention, and does it really matter anyway?  The only reason I bring it up is because a rejection reason *is* that it is copied content, so it must matter!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can flag **any** post that uses that tag for moderator attention, using the "Other" reason and explaining exactly why you are flagging.

I have rolled back the entry.

Comment: Ah right, I didn't think of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to flag any tag. Only option to flag is flagging any question tagged with that tag (not necessary but it's better) using "other" reason. But before flagging you should probably suggest a tag edit and add attribution yourself. If it is not accepted then flag a post.